# How can I reset index to 0

Tags: php, mysql

i should make a "cheque" and there should be (Index,id,....), but index should reset after 100, but id must be auto_incremented.
Here is my code what i did. I didnt get how can i reset index to 0. I cant even show the indexs value, it shows 0 everytime when i add something.

```
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "dbcar";

    $number = "";
    $state_number = "";
    $model = "";
    $status = "";
    $conditions = "";
    $date = "";
    $number_index = "1";

    $connect = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database);

    echo "<h1>Report Log </h1>";
    $sqlget = "SELECT * FROM carserv ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1";
    $sqldata = mysqli_query($connect,$sqlget) or die("error");

    echo "<table>";
    echo"<tr>
    <th>INDEX</th>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>State Number</th>
    <th>Model</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Condition</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    </tr>";


    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        echo" <tr><td>";
        echo $row['number_index'];
        echo" </td><td>";
        echo $row['number'];
        echo" </td><td>";
        echo $row['state_number'];
        echo" </td><td>";
        echo $row['model'];
        echo" </td><td>";
        echo $row['status'];
        echo" </td><td>";
        echo $row['conditions'];
        echo" </td><td>";
        echo $row['date'];
        echo" </td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    function getPosts(){
        $posts = array();
        $posts[0] = $_POST['state_number'];
        $posts[1] = $_POST['number'];
        $posts[2] = $_POST['model'];
        $posts[3] = $_POST['status'];
        $posts[4] = $_POST['conditions'];
        $posts[6] = $_POST['number_index'];
        return $posts;
    }
?>
```

and here is my output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOoBE.jpg

Comment: `SELECT` doesn't change a database, `INSERT/UPDATE` do. Hard to say what your real code is.

Comment: Plus, `INDEX` is a MySQL reserved word https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html - seeing that screenshot of yours.

Comment: i can show you my whole code if you want

Comment: someone already posted an answer for you below

Answer (score 0):

Take look in your phpmyadmin page there is auto_increment option you need to just have two field check auto increment for id field and for index you just fetch it and save it to db in another field with name number_index(because index is a reserved word).

Reset your db to O by doing something like this is your counter_update.php

```
   if($_POST['index_reset']) {
   $index_reset = $_POST[index_reset];
   mysql_connect("server", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 
   mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());
   $sql = 'UPDATE counters SET number_index =\'0\' WHERE Page = \'$index_reset\';';
  }
```

And html side something like this

```
 $page_reset = "<form id='Reset' action='counter_update.php' method='post'>
<button type='submit' name='index_reset' value='$formPage'>RESET</button>
</form>";
```

Comment: yeah but how can i add two field with auto_increment? it says that you can only ad 1 auto_increment and i have auto_increment - number

Comment: dude just id as auto increment and number_index should be provided from backend and save it to db and rest it when reach hundered

Comment: how can i do that ? i am making that for 2 days and didnt get it, sorry im starter in php, mysql